# What's the relationship between forkOn and the -qm RTS flag?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, concurrency

Suppose that I have a program that only spawn threads using `forkOn`. In such scenario, there will be no load balancing of Haskell threads among different capabilities. So is there a difference in executing this program with and without `+RTS -qm`?

According to the documentation, `-qm` disables the thread migration, which I think it has a similar effect of using only `forkOn`. Am I correct in this assumption? I'm sure not how clear the documentation is in this regard.

Answer (score 4):

I'm no expert on the subject, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

GHC (The Haskell compiler) can have one or multiple HECs (Haskell Execution Context, also known as cap or capability). With runtime flag `+RTS -N <number>` or [`setNumCapabilities`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:setNumCapabilities) function it's possible to define how many those HECs are available for program. One HEC is one operating system thread. The runtime scheduler distributes Haskell lightweight threads between HECs.

With `forkOn` function, it's possible to select which HEC the thread is ran on. [`getNumCapabilities`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:getNumCapabilities) returns the number of capabilities (HECs).

Thread migration means that Haskell threads can be migrated (moved) to another HEC. The runtime flag `+RTS -qm` disables this thread migration.

Documentation about [`forkOn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:forkOn) states that

> Like [forkIO](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:forkIO), but lets you specify on which capability the thread should run. Unlike a forkIO thread, a thread created by forkOn will stay on the same capability for its entire lifetime (forkIO threads can migrate between capabilities according to the scheduling policy).

so with `forkOn` it's possible to select one single HEC the thread is ran in.

Compared to [`forkIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:forkIO) which states that

> Foreign calls made by this thread are not guaranteed to be made by any particular OS thread; if you need foreign calls to be made by a particular OS thread, then use forkOS instead.

Now, are `forkOn` function and `+RTS -qm` (disabled thread migration) the same thing? Probably not. With `forkOn` user explicitly selects which HEC the Haskell thread is ran on (for example it's possible to put all Haskell threads into same HEC). With `+RTS -qm` and `forkIO` the Haskell threads don't switch between HECs, but there's no way knowing which HEC the Haskell thread spawned by `forkIO` ends in.

References:

- [Runtime Support for Multicore Haskell](http://research-srv.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/parallel/multicore-ghc.pdf)
- [The GHC scheduler](http://blog.ezyang.com/2013/01/the-ghc-scheduler/)
- [GHC(STG,Cmm,asm) illustrated](https://takenobu-hs.github.io/downloads/haskell_ghc_illustrated.pdf)